# Django and Stripe MultiValueDictKeyError at /checkout/ "'stripeToken'"

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

```
    views.py
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    import stripe


    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

    # Create your views here.
    @login_required
    def checkout(request):
        publishKey = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
        if request.method == 'POST':
            token = request.POST['stripeToken']
                try:
                stripe.Charge.create(
                    amount=1000,
                    currency="usd",
                    card=token,


                    description="Charge for test@example.com"
    )
            except stripe.CardError:
                # The card has been declined
                pass
            # Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card

        context = {'publishKey': publishKey

                    }
        template = 'checkout.html'
        return render(request, template, context)



When i run my views.py gives me this error -    MultiValueDictKeyError at /checkout/
"'stripeToken'"

here is my checkout.py
MultiValueDictKeyError at /checkout/
"'stripeToken'"
```

that is my checkout.py
please help out i would appreciate it. 
Im making a website to take payments eventually but when i run it i get that error i think its coming from the views.py but am not to sure would like to get some feed back from some djangonites or pythoners thanks

Answer (score 1):

Django raises [this error](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.__getitem__) when the requested key, `stripeToken` in this example, does not exist in `request.POST`. You may want to check your `POST` form data for your request.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from django.utils.datastructures import MultiValueDict as MVD
>>> data = MVD({'name': ['John'], 'email': ['j@yahoo.com']})
>>> data['name']
'John'
>>> data['email']
'j@yahoo.com'
```

> This class [`MultiValueDict`] exists to solve the irritating problem
>   raised by cgi.parse_qs, which returns a list for every key, even
>   though most Web forms submit single name-value pairs.

---

> `cgi.parse_qs`: Parse a query string given as a string argument (data of type application/x-www-form-urlencoded). Data are returned as
>   a dictionary.  The dictionary keys are the unique query variable names
>   and the values are lists of values for each name.

---

Now with a non-existent key:

```
>>> data['apple']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/7stud/.virtualenvs/django186p34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 322, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'apple'"
```

See how the last line says `...MultiValueDictKeyError: "'apple'"`?  See how the key `'apple'` doesn't exist in the MultiValueDict created in the django console above?

See how you wrote:

```
request.POST['stripeToken']
```

and you got a similar error??  `request.POST` is a `MultiValueDict` which contains the key/value pairs from the POST data.  The error is saying that `"stripeToken"` is not a key in the MultiValueDict, which means there was no key/value pair in the POST data with the key `'stripeToken'`.

If the data came from an html form, that means there was no form input element with its `name` attribute set to "stripeToken", e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="stripeToken">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the cause of the problem was in checkout.html. I was using this

```
 Stripe.setPublishableKey({{ publishkey }});
```

Instead of

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey('{{ publishkey }}');
```

Correcting it solved the error for me

Answer (score 0):

Refresh your publishable and secret api keys, delete all test data then try apply print the token on your terminal to see if its actually coming through :

```
if 'stripeToken' in request.POST:   
        print(request.POST['stripeToken'])
```